# a:-webkit-any-link { text-decoration: underline; } can only be written by inline-style, why?

Tags: html, css, ejs

```css
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:-webkit-any-link{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

/*Navigation*/

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)
}

.nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)
}

.search-container{
    position: fixed;
    top:3rem;
    right:0;
}

#search-container a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
 <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="main-nav nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store">STORE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="fans">FANS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</header>

        <section class="search-container" id="search-container">
            <input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="Search..">
            <p id="feedback"></p>
            <a href="/store?category=music" >MUSIC</a>
            <a href="/store?category=merch" >MERCH</a>
            <a href="/purchase" style="text-decoration: none">CART</a>
        </section>
```

So I have those links in an EJS file and I want them to not have underline. In the same file I have some `<nav class="nav"><li><a href="/store">Link</a></li></nav>`that I easily wrote

```css
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and it works like charm. But somehow those below just won't!

```html
<section class="search-container" id="search-container">
    <a href="/store?category=music" >MUSIC</a>
    <a href="/store?category=merch" >MERCH</a>
    <a href="/purchase" style="text-decoration: none">CART</a>
</section>
```

I tried googling and various methods. Check out what I've tried:

```css
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:-webkit-any-link{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

#search-container a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

None of the above works, and I see it was the

```css
a:-webkit-any-link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

always showing up. But judging from any above code, they should have been overwritten, shouldn't they?

In the end I tried the inline style such as:

```html
<a href="/purchase" class="btn btn-primary" style="text-decoration: none">CART</a>
```

It finally works. Fyi, 
1. the style.css is properly linked, otherwise the nav links won't work nor do other styles. 
2. The problem appears in both Chromium and Firefox on Linux. 
3. I tried Snippets but it can not duplicate my problem at all. 
4. I did use a lot of techniques, such as adding id, or even !important, but none seems to overwrite the stubborn a:-webkit-any-link { text-decoration: underline; }.

I just wonder why is this happening?

Comment: Consider using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide an example showing the bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce your issue. You may also want to note what browser(s) you've noticed the behavior in.

Comment: If it works inline but not in CSS, it's likely that your CSS isn't specific enough and is being overridden elsewhere. **Or** your CSS isn't properly linked to your document and isn't being applied at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to copy my css and repaste it back. Somehow it works now and I no longer need the inline-style. No idea but it solved the problem!

Comment: It's important to note that CSS files are cached by your browser. You can make a handful of changes to your CSS, but your browser won't go and re-fetch the file because it thinks it has the most up-to-date version already. For some tips on how to circumvent this: [Strategies for Cache-Busting CSS](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/). (In Chrome, if you right-click on the refresh button with the developer console open, you get the option to clear the cache. Or, just use the hotkey: `CTRL`+`F5`). This may not be related, but just a tip.

Comment: Thank you @Tyler Roper, yes I will take those in mind and next time will go through all the above suggestion when problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case cursor pointer was not showing when the `<a>` tag didn't have `href` or `[routerLink]` defined (navigation was actually done on click event and `router.navigate()`).

I defined empty `[routerLink]=""` and the cursor pointer is now shown and navigation isn't affected. (This wasn't the case with using empty `href=""` instead).

Also worth mentioning, adding `[routerLink]` to element other than `<a>` wouldn't get me the cursor as `href` does. Adding `cursor: pointer` to the styling of an element did the thing locally but wasn't working when deployed to server.

```
<a>doesnt't have a cursor pointer</a>
<a href="">has a cursor pointer</a>
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="navigate()">has a cursor pointer</a>
```